# Serverless Dataproc Error- Batch ID is required

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

While trying to submit a spark job using Serverless Dataproc using rest API
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/quickstarts/spark-batch#dataproc_serverless_create_batch_workload-drest

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
"https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/locations/region/batches"
```

I got this error response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Batch ID is required",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

What Am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested with gcloud `--log-http`:

```
$ gcloud dataproc batches submit spark --log-http \
    --jars=file:///usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar \
    --class=org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    -- 1000
...
==== request start ====
uri: https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/locations/us-west1/batches?alt=json&batchId=21dd24ca279a4603926d4e59d65bfaf9&requestId=21dd24ca279a4603926d4e59d65bfaf9
method: POST
...
```

Note the `batchId=21dd24ca279a4603926d4e59d65bfaf9` in the URL.

I also tested manually set the ID with `--batch`:

```
$ gcloud dataproc batches submit spark --log-http  \
  --batch=foobar \
  --jars=file:///usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar \
  --class=org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  -- 1000

...
==== request start ====
uri: https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/locations/us-west1/batches?alt=json&batchId=foobar&requestId=c7b5a753cac4483da21b1ba1c6c2a2d1
method: POST
...
```

Seems like the REST API requires a `batchId` parameter in the URL, but when using gcloud it automatically generates one.